# Can't see materials on particular object, but they appear in the UV layout? See picture

Tags: texturing

[image: screen shot of scene, shows blank object, and UV / diffuse map layout in Paint]

Can't see materials on particular object, but they appear in the UV layout? Other objects in the scene are fine. Anyt ideas ?

Comment: Hello, how does your node organization look like? Maybe pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll upload now.  Node is really simple, I just plugged an image texture in . Although, I imported the model as an .fbx , andI think the textures are already in the there somewhere.